# I am missing some point about Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I don't get the argumentation of [Cantor's theorem proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). I must have gone wrong or misunderstood something somewhere so I will try to explain my reasoning below.

> Theorem (Cantor) Let $f$ be a map from set $A$ to its power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$.  Then $f : A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is not surjective.  As a consequence, $\operatorname{card}(A) < \operatorname{card}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ holds for any set $A$

The theorem is straightforward enough, we need to show that $f$ is not surjective, meaning that there is some element $y \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that there is no $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. The proof is where I run into trouble.

> **Proof** Consider the set $ B=\{x \in A \mid x \notin f(x)\}$.  Suppose to the contrary that $f$ is surjective.  Then there exists $\xi\in A$ such that $f(\xi)=B$.  But by construction, $\xi \in B \iff \xi \notin f(\xi)= B $.  This is a contradiction.  Thus, $f$ cannot be surjective.  On the other hand, $g : A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ defined by $x \mapsto \{x\}$ is an injective map.  Consequently, we must have $\operatorname{card}(A) < \operatorname{card}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

I do not understand the third sentence in the proof. It says that "if $f$ is surjective, then there exists some $\xi \in A$ such that $f(\xi) = B$".

I do not see why such a $\xi$ must exist if $f$ is surjective. because consider the injective/surjective mapping of $f: A \mapsto C$ where $f$ is the identity function and $A$ and $C$ both contain the same single element. There exists no $\xi \in A$ such that $f(\xi)$ = B and $f$ is surjective. Have I misunderstood something? How can I rectify my above statements with the logic of the proof?

Comment: $f$ is a function with codomain the powerset, and $B$ belongs to the powerset - so if $f$ is surjective, $B$ must lie in the image of $f$. There is no claim that $B$ lies in the image of any surjective function between any two sets...

Comment: The $B$ is the $y$ that you said one needed to find.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \{x\}$ is *not* surjective onto the powerset of its domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are forgetting the fact that $f$ is surjective onto the power set of $A$. If $A$ is  a singleton then power set of $A$ is not a singleton.  It contains the empty set $\Phi$ also.

Existence of $\xi$ in the proof is the very definition of surjectivity.